# SoapUI: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, soapui

Currently using the open source version of SoapUI 5.5.0. I am trying to run a REST Request. In Postman I am able to bypass this issue by turning off SSL verification but that does not seem possible in SoapUI.

When I try to run a request I am getting the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

I have tried adding:

- `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.https.protocols="SSLv3,TLSv1.2"` to `SoapUI.bat`
- `-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2,SSLv3` to `SoapUI-X.X.X.vmoptions`

Neither of these solutions work. I am not sure that the problem exists on the SoapUI side anymore.

Comment: @kriegaex In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid link-rot), we prefer answer that provide at least a summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Java comes with its own CA TrustStore. SoapUI, at least on Windows, comes with bundled Java, usually very outdated version of Java. we know that SoapUI is intelligent enough, that if it does not find the bundled Java it will look elsewhere ($PATH, $JAVA_HOME). So we go to your SoapUI install directory and renamed jre to jre.ignore.